# Custom UIButton for Facebook Login

Tags: swift, facebook-login, firebase-authentication, facebook-sdk-4.x, swift2

I have been working on a little project, and I need people to sign in/log in using Facebook/Google. It has been working perfectly so far with Google's Firebase Auth.

I basically works with Facebook, so all the functionality is okay.

Now I would like to "style" it a bit, and give it a customised look. I can't seem to make that happen.

I have made a UIButton that I can move around, change shape of and basically control everything. I would like to make my UIButton do the *exact* same as the native Facebook LoginButton.

I went to Facebook's own documentation. I tried everything. I copy/pasted the code they have written, it gives multiple errors. I tried every tutorial I could find, nothing helped. One tutorial got me a bit of the way, but did not quite make it. 
Facebook's code that I copied: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login

Thanks a lot in advance, I hope someone can help me out.

[image]

Here is my code, if that helps:

```
import UIKit
import FacebookLogin
import FacebookCore
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FirebaseAuth

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

let loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()

@IBOutlet weak var SpinnerLogin: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loginButton.isHidden = true

    FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        if let user = user {
            // User is signed in.

            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let homeViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeView")

            self.present(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


        } else {
            // No user is signed in.

            self.loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends" ]
            self.loginButton.center = self.view.center
            self.loginButton.delegate = self
            self.view.addSubview(self.loginButton)


            self.loginButton.isHidden = false


        }
    }

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Tells us if person is logged in
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

    self.loginButton.isHidden = true

    if (error != nil) {
        //Handle error
        self.loginButton.isHidden = false
    }

    else if (result.isCancelled) {
        //Handle cancel event
        self.loginButton.isHidden = false

    }

    else {

    SpinnerLogin.startAnimating()

    let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in

        print("User Logged in to Facebook")
        print("You are now signed in to Firebase")
    }
    }
}

//Tells us if person logged out
func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {

    print("User did log out")
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it. I don't now if its recommended, but it works perfectly.

1. Add a UIView to your storyboard, and give it the shape and size that
   you want.
2. Give the UIView a FBSDKLoginButton subclass - like this: [UIView with FBSDKLoginButton Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmMst.png)

Now in your swift file, do like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewFBLogin: FBSDKLoginButton! = FBSDKLoginButton()
```

In your viewDidLoad do this:

```
viewFBLogin.delegate = self
```

And then you can decide which permission you want and all that, I followed the Firebase Documentation so here is how it looks for me:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //THIS LINE IS SUPER IMPORTANT, OTHERWISE THE REST OF THE CODE WONT KNOW IF USER IS LOGGED IN OR OUT
    viewFBLogin.delegate = self

    viewFBLogin.layer.cornerRadius = 20

    FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        if let user = user {
            // User is signed in.

            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let homeViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeView")

            self.present(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


        } else {
            // No user is signed in.

            self.viewFBLogin.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends" ]
            self.viewFBLogin.isHidden = false


        }
    }

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Tells us if person is logged in - DOES NOT WORK WITHOUT DELEGATE UP TOP
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

    self.viewFBLogin.isHidden = true

    if (error != nil) {
        //Handle error
        self.viewFBLogin.isHidden = false
    }

    else if (result.isCancelled) {
        //Handle cancel event
        self.viewFBLogin.isHidden = false

    }

    else {

    SpinnerLogin.startAnimating()

    let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in

        print("User Logged in to Facebook")
        print("You are now signed in to Firebase")
    }
    }
}

//Tells us if person logged out - DOES NOT WORK WITHOUT DELEGATE UP TOP
func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {

    print("User did log out")
}
```

Hope that helps, if anybody was in the same situation as I was.